Evaluating $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}}^0{xy^2}\, dxdy$ via polar coordinates
I want to evaluate the following specifically with polar coordinates: $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}}^0{xy^2}\, dxdy$
I see the inner integral has $-\sqrt{1-(y-1)^2}\leq x\leq 0$ which is a “left semi-circle” centred at $(0,1)$, and $0\leq y\leq 2$. I’m really struggling to translate these into a polar integration region. I feel like the subsequent part of the problem will be ok with $x=r\cos\theta, y=r\sin\theta$ etc, but I can’t get past the bounds yet. Also, is there any way to see intuitively why the answer is negative? (checked on WFA)

Hint: pretend the second Cartesian coordinate is $Y=y-1$ instead. Could you link to your check of the area? I get it to be positive with other software.

@J.G. thanks, let me see if I can link the calculation - I’m starting to think I put it in wrong!

@J.G. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bx*Power%5By%2C2%5D%2C%7Bx%2C-Sqrt%5B1-Power%5B%5C%2840%29y-1%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%2C0%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2C2%7D%5D let me know if the link works

I had to copy-paste that. You know what? I think my software misled me, because I get the same answer as WA when I work it out in polar coordinates as per my original suggestion. As to why it's negative, you're integrating on an $x<0$ region, so the integrand's $x$ factor is negative.

Oh ok, that makes sense. I’ll see if I can work through your hint now.

The shape you drew is in the second quadrant only, and you can check that for any $\theta \in (\pi/2,\pi)$, a ray from the origin at the angle $\theta$ will hit the shape at at least one point (draw a picture to check this). So the bounds for $\theta$ are $\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi$. For a fixed angle $\theta$ in this range, the range of values for $r$ such that $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ is inside the shape is $0$ to whatever radius puts $(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta)$ on the edge of the circle $x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1$.
See if you can write out the integral in polar coordinates now. If not, click below.

 The circle can be expressed as $$x^2 + (y-1)^2 = 1,$$ or equivalently $$x^2 + y^2-2y = 0.$$


 Now sub in $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$ to get $$r^2-2r\sin\theta = 0,$$ which gives us $r = 2\sin\theta$ as the upper bound for $r$ in terms of $\theta$.

As for why the integral is negative, notice that over the entire shape, $x \le 0$ and $y^2 \ge 0$. Hence $xy^2 \le 0$ over the entire region of integration, and thus, the integral will be non-positive.

I think I must be missing something because $\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\sin\theta}{r^4\cos\theta \sin^2\theta , dr d\theta}$ doesn’t give the answer that WA has. Are the bounds wrong here?

@AnthonyML I made a minor mistake in that the upper bound for $r$ should be $2\sin \theta$ not $\sin \theta$. Try it with this upper bound.
